# If I don't see the "Full HTML" and "Filtered HTML" input formats, is it OK to add them manually?

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I currently only have a "plain text" format.
Is it ok for me to add additional "Text formats" on the "Configuration" screen? Eg. Full html, filtered html etc?

Or should these have been created automatically when I installed the ckeditor and IMCE modules?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Drupal 7 includes `plain text`, `filtered HTML`, and `full HTML` text formats.

If you are not seeing these as choices, you are probably not logged in as an administrator and you do not have the appropriate permissions.

Non-administrators are not given access to `full HTML` by default because this can be a security risk.

Try logging in as an administrator and going to the permissions management page.  Verify the permissions for `Use the Filtered HTML text format` etc. under **Filters**.

Of course, if you need an input filter with a custom configuration, you can certainly create your own.  Just be careful to not give your users any input options they shouldn't have.

Comment: Where is permissions management?

Comment: The permissions management page is the one that lists all the permissions and which roles have or do not have them.  On Drupal 7, `/admin/people/permissions`.

Comment: Thanks. I can only see the following options:
Filter
Administer text formats and filters
Use the Filtered HTML text format

And the Filtered HTML is there because I added it manually. It wasn't there by default even though I'm running drupal 7.

By the way, I am always logged in as admin.

Comment: @kine456 If you aren't already, log in as user 1, the first user you created when you set up Drupal, and try again.  User 1 has special permissions (access to everything).

Comment: Actually, if you do a minimal install of Drupal, these formats are NOT added automatically. The same may apply to any installation profile other than "Standard".